# VB script to copy from excel to word and then from word into the clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I wish I could just copy straight from excel but the program that I am copying into doesn't allow that.

This is what I have so far.

```
Sub exceltoword()
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Set RangeToCopy = Range("A2")
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = New Word.Application
WordApp.Visible = True
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
RangeToCopy.Copy
WordDoc.Words(1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:001"))
WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:005"))

Set RangeToCopy = Range("B2")
Set WordApp = New Word.Application
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
RangeToCopy.Copy
WordDoc.Words(1).PasteExcelTable False, False, False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:001"))
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Copy
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:001"))
ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges


End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're trying to copy from Excel to Word? That's certainly possible, Word allows this.  What errors are you getting? What output are you seeing that isn't what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

With a simple google search of how to copy from excel to word is where I found the below, I added comments that tell you where to change variables, you can add multiple tables pasted to any bookmarks you set in word, make sure you set your references.

your code will look something like this after you declare you word application

Option Base 1 'Force arrays to start at 1 instead of 0

```
Sub ExcelTablesToWord()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table
Dim TableArray As Variant
Dim BookmarkArray As Variant

'List of Table Names (To Copy)
  TableArray = Array("MAKE YOUR TABLE ARRAY IN EXCEL AND PUT THE NAME HERE",)

'List of Word Document Bookmarks (To Paste To  - in word goto Insert->Bookmark)
  BookmarkArray = Array("BOOKMARK NAME FROM MICROSOFT WORD DOC HERE")

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Set Variable Equal To Destination Word Document
  On Error GoTo WordDocNotFound
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents("FULL FILE PATH TO YOUR WORD DOCUMENT")
  On Error GoTo 0

'Loop Through and Copy/Paste Multiple Excel Tables
  For x = LBound(TableArray) To UBound(TableArray)

    'Copy Table Range from Excel
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(x).ListObjects(TableArray(x)).Range
      tbl.Copy

    'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5)
      myDoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkArray(x)).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
      Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(x)
      WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

  Next x

'Completion Message
  MsgBox "Copy/Pasting Complete!", vbInformation
  GoTo EndRoutine

'ERROR HANDLER
WordDocNotFound:
  MsgBox "Microsoft Word file 'Excel Table Word Report.docx' is not currently open, aborting.", 16

'Put Stuff Back The Way It Was Found
EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Basically you set your variables to the word application, define the arrays you want to paste in your excel sheet (in your instance B5?) then it will loop through and paste your arrays to the Bookmarks you set in your word document, which you can set to any location in your word document.